# Get the highest conformity between two strings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2014, string-comparison

Is the Levenshtein function the correct/best function to find the highest conformity between two strings?

eg:

```
string1 = CCC14E0APJ
string2 = CCC14E0APJ123
```

My end result should say that `CCC14E0APJ` is the master product of `CCC14E0APJ123`.
I can not do a exact match because some products will look like this.

```
CCC14E0AP
CCC14E0APJ
CCC14E0APK
```

which are all totally different products.
The master is always a 100% matching string for the longest found string. 
For product abcde123, if there is a abcde in my master table, thats the master. If there is only abc, thats the master.

Comment: Do the prefixes of the strings always agree, or could that vary as well?

Comment: always agree, there should be an exact match on all characters and their order

Comment: Why is CCC14E0APJ123 higher than CCC14E0AP, CCC14E0APK?

Comment: It's not. CCC14E0APJ = master product, CCC14E0APJxxxxx = sub product x

Comment: And CCC14E0AP master of CCC14E0APJ & CCC14E0APK ?

Comment: Good question... The longest possible string in the table which matches exactly is the master. For CCC14E0APJ, if there is a CCC14E0AP, thats the master. If the highest matching string is CCC14E0A , thats the master

Comment: Does your parent/child construct denote a hierarchy of arbitrary depth? could it be, for example, that CC14E0 is a product, too, and that CC14E0APJ is a child of it? Can you please provide a database schema and a table holding all available products?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Would love to provide a fiddle but it only brings up errors for sqlserver2008 and 2014.
We are using SqlServer2016. CC14E0 Could be a master product. Thats why i need to get the longest string in the master table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need fancy *How-close-is-the-string*-functions, but rather compare the beginning of a string with all other strings, if they start with the same string. If so, the shorter is the **parent** of the longer...

With the following query you would get the *ParentID*, even in a hierarchical system:

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(YourID VARCHAR(100),ParentID VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @dummy(YourID) VALUES
 ('CCC14E0AP')
,('CCC14E0APJ')
,('CCC14E0APK')
,('CCC14E0APK_1')
,('CCC14E');

WITH DependingIDs AS
(
    SELECT d.ParentID
          ,d.YourID
          ,d2.YourID AS dependingID
          ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY d.YourID ORDER BY LEN(d2.YourID) DESC) AS NextLenght
    FROM @dummy AS d
    INNER JOIN @dummy AS d2 ON d.YourID LIKE d2.YourID + '%' AND d.YourID<>d2.YourID
)
UPDATE DependingIDs SET ParentID=dependingID
WHERE NextLenght=1;

SELECT * FROM @dummy
```

This is the result

```
YourID       ParentID
CCC14E0AP    CCC14E
CCC14E0APJ   CCC14E0AP
CCC14E0APK   CCC14E0AP
CCC14E0APK_1 CCC14E0APK
CCC14E       NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

For each row you just detect the max substring using `APPLY` operator:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( p VARCHAR(MAX) );

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'A' ),
        ( 'AAAA' ),
        ( 'AA' ),
        ( 'BBB' ),
        ( 'BBBB' ),
        ( 'BBBBB' ),
        ( 'BBBBB' ),
        ( 'C' )

SELECT  *
FROM    @t t
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 p
                      FROM      @t
                      WHERE     t.p <> p AND t.p LIKE p + '%'
                      ORDER BY  LEN(p) DESC
                    ) ca
```

Output:

```
A       NULL
AAAA    AA
AA      A
BBB     NULL
BBBB    BBB
BBBBB   BBBB
BBBBB   BBBB
C       NULL
```

Comment: Your solution worked as well but Shnugo's solution was first and also worked and i'm not able to tell the pros and cons about both solutions.

Comment: @jrdev22 In this case you could vote the answer up by cklicking on the triangle. Voting and accepting are two separate steps here on SO. Since you've crossed the 15-rep-point-border yourself, you are asked to vote on any contribution you like or dislike. This is the way to say *Thank you* on SO... Happy Coding! (btw: +1 from my side)